# CMake Error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3"

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, eigen3, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to build a project on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and Kinetic. I keep getting the following CMake error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any of the following names:

Eigen3Config.cmake
eigen3-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
frontend/interactive_marker_node/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

The package libeigen3-dev is installed and the file Eigen3Config.cmake can be found in /usr/lib/cmake:

```
 $ apt list libeigen3-dev
 Listing... Done
 libeigen3-dev/xenial,xenial,now 3.3~beta1-2 all [installed]
 $ ls /usr/include/eigen3/
 Eigen  signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library  unsupported
 $ ls /usr/lib/cmake/eigen3/
 Eigen3Config.cmake  UseEigen3.cmake
```

The mentioned CMakeLists.txt is given in the following listing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(interactive_marker_node)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(
  catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  Eigen3
  roscpp
  rospy
  dynamic_reconfigure
  moveit_visual_tools
)
if(NOT EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
[...]
```

I tried to set Eigen3_DIR, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH as well as upgrading and reinstalling libeigen3-dev. No success so far. The problem is related to these questions:

https://answers.ros.org/question/253181/howto-eigen-installation/

https://answers.ros.org/question/215080/how-to-add-the-installation-prefix-of-eigen3-to-cmake_prefix_path-or-set-eigen3_dir-to-a-directory-containing-one-of-the-above-files/

https://answers.ros.org/question/250727/error-findeigen3cmake-during-install-kinetic-on-rpi/

The given answers somehow did not work for me or do not apply to my system.

Did anyone experience the same issue and found a solution? My last idea would be to download and install Eigen3 manually but I would prefer to stay with the officiall repository...

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309696/cmake-error:-could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22eigen3%22/) by [jotwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/38780/jotwe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> find_package(
> ```

```
  catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  Eigen3
  [..]
```

Eigen is not a ROS package, so you cannot use `find_package(catkin .. )` with it.

You'll need to use a regular `find_package(Eigen3 ..)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jotwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/38780/jotwe/) on 2018-12-04**:
Thanks, that solved the problem for me!